# Updating SystemJS from 0.21 to 6.x with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, systemjs

There a UMD bundle with React application that is hosted on CDN and is loaded dynamically when needed. React and ReactDOM are not bundled and it's expected that environment will have them available. The whole application is built using Webpack. I have the following code with SystemJS@0.21 that works:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SystemJS from 'systemjs/dist/system-production'; // 0.21

SystemJS.registry.set('React', SystemJS.newModule(React));
SystemJS.registry.set('ReactDOM', SystemJS.newModule(ReactDOM));

const URL = 'https://example.com/bundle.js'; // UMD bundle

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SystemJS.import(URL).then(module => this.setState({ module }));
  }

  render() {
    const Component = this.state.module?.default;

    return Component ? <Component /> : null;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it work with SystemJS@6.0, or load any other way? It works now but using old version sits uneasily with me. Changing format of downloaded package from UMD to SystemJS is next to impossible because there's a lot of consumers that I don't control.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get SystemJS 6.6.1 working in an Angular project in order to laod a UMD bundle.
You can find the details over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917606/2528609.

The most important part, I think, is that you need to load an additional script to handle UMD modules => `"node_modules/systemjs/dist/extras/amd.js"`