# es6: how to add dependencies to dynamic import

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want to dynamically load a (angular) library, so I use `import` to load the library.

```
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ url).then(module => {
   console.log('Got ya!');
});
```

I add the `/* webpackIgnore: true */` so Webpack will not attempt to add it to the bundle at build time.
This seems to work, but now the imports of the library cannot be loaded. I get

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@angular/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

This seems to be caused by imports of classes in the external library. For example

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
```

I managed to get things working with SystemJS, but I wanted to try to achieve the same without the extra SystemJS (6.6) library. See [SystemJS 6.x set/register modules or provide mapping when dynamically loading module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634659/systemjs-6-x-set-register-modules-or-provide-mapping-when-dynamically-loading-mo/63917606#63917606) for that solution.

But without SystemJS, is it possible to load all dependencies of the external module too? Or even better, re-use the already loaded dependencies, such as @angular/core...?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I guess I could use importmap as described here: https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/in-2020-go-bundler-free-eb29c1f05fc9 (https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims/blob/master/src/es-module-shims.js).

That could translate the `@angular/core` into something like `./node_modules/@angular/core`.

The thing that still remains then is how to re-use an already loaded module from the host application. In SystemJS we could register such modules to be used instead of being fetched.

Comment: If your using npm modules, you need to use a bundler.  "@anglular/core" is not a url.  A bundler can handle this but your browser can't.  I have not used Webpack for a while, but the last I remember it has code splitting built in.  So if you do a dynamic import it will import dynamically.  More info -> https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: You need to provide a path, not a package name. it's probably something like `"./node_modules/@angular/core"`, but that's a guess since I can't know how you're deploying your code.

Comment: Mind providing your webconfig.js? As well as the `url` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Just take any dependency you need to access from a dynamic module via `import {...}` and put it somewhere in the global scope. Then, create an import map that simply re-exports the value from the global scope with the correct name. Once that's done, you could be able to pull them with `import {...}` inside other modules as well as `import()` on the top-level.

Edit: I created an NPM module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-mapper

```js
// Preexisting class...
class Foo {};

// Put the class somewhere we can find it later...
globalThis['##IMPORTS##'] = { '@foo/Foo': Foo };

// Put the class in an importMap
const importMap = document.createElement('script');
importMap.setAttribute('type', 'importmap');
importMap.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
  imports: {
    // This is the meat-and-potatoes of our shim:
    '@foo/Foo': 'data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(
      `export const Foo = globalThis['##IMPORTS##']['@foo/Foo']`
    ),

    // This would actually live in a separate file:
    '@bar/Bar': 'data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(`
      import { Foo } from '@foo/Foo';
      export class Bar extends Foo {};
    `),
  }
});

// Append the importMap to the document head
document.head.append(importMap);

// Clean it up.
importMap.remove();

// Check the imports
import('@foo/Foo').then(foo => console.log(foo));
import('@bar/Bar').then(bar => console.log(bar));
```